# Why MatDialogRef require 3 type argument(s)?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

Am trying to use the angular material dialog component. I used it in the past and I had no problem with it. But somehow i can't use it the way i used it in the past. here is my implementation:

```
export class FilterDialogComponent implements OnInit {

public clientDepartementFilter: string;
public partnerDepartmentFilter: string;
public checkboxFilters: CheckboxFilters;

constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<FilterDialogComponent>,
          @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {

this.checkboxFilters = data.checkboxFilters;
this.clientDepartementFilter = data.clientDepartementFilter;
this.partnerDepartmentFilter = data.partnerDepartmentFilter;
}

closeDialog(): void {
this.dialogRef.close({ data: this.clientDepartementFilter });
}
```

And i open it this way:

```
public openDialog(): void {
this.dialog.open(FilterDialogComponent, {
  data: {
    checkboxFilters: this.checkboxFilters,
    clientDepartementFilter: this.clientDepartementFilter,
    partnerDepartmentFilter: this.partnerDepartmentFilter
  }
}).afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

}

My code compile but I have an error when I create a reference of the current dialog with

```
public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<FilterDialogComponent>
```

the error is the following:

> TS2314: Generic type 'MatDialogRef' requires 3 type argument(s)

when I add types any in the MatDialog the error goes away but i can't compile my code anymore...

Now I have the following error:

> error TS2707: Generic type 'MatDialogRef' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

I tried to update angular material angularCli and typescript but it still won't compile.

> "@angular/cli": "^1.7.2",
>
> "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
>
> "typescript": "^2.4.2"
>
> "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",

Any suggestions or idea of why it happens?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`MatDialogRef` generic accepts [1 or 2 type arguments](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/5.2.4/src/lib/dialog/dialog-ref.ts#L29).

[`angular-material`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material) is AngularJS library. `@angular/material` should be used instead.

Comment: I am using @angular/material 5.2.4. I edited my question.

Comment: Where did this angular-material come from then? @angular/material 5.2.4 requires Angular 6. Make sure you're installing the version that is compatible with your dependencies.

Comment: I removed angular-material from my package.json and updated @angular/cli and now it work for the MatDialogRef but now the function openDialog() has the following error : Argument type {data: {CheckboxFilters, clientDepartmentFilter: string, partnerDepartmentFilter: string}} is not assignable to paramter type MatDialogConfig<D>

Comment: Not sure what's going on there, because D is supposed to be `any` by default https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/5.2.4/src/lib/dialog/dialog.ts#L112 . Consider providing a way to replicate the problem (e.g. Stackblitz) if the problem persists.